# calling onOptionsItemSelected explicitly

Tags: android, android-menu

I have a Save MenuItem. This has a `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` function. It's triggered when I click on the Save menu. However, I want to call this function explicitely when the user tries to navidate to another activity without saving.
So basically how can I call this `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` from another function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do one thing all the code you written in this method within for save just copy and paste in you created method for e.g.

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.save:
       saveMe();
    break;
    }
}

private void saveMe(){
    // write your save code here
}
```

now you can call this method when user navigate to another activity

Answer (score 1):

Have a function named `showSaveMenu()` and inside it show the save menu if user has not saved already. Call this function from each possible exit point from the activity i.e. `onBackPressed()` or from any where you start another activity and also from `onOptionsItemselected()`....

Answer (score 0):

just call invalidateOptionsMenu().